# Twitter's bootstrap datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, datetimepicker

Hi I am using the following plugin to show datetime in my input fields the problem is that i can't get the value and can't understand how to do it. [The plugin](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I can't understand what is the function but for sure this is not working:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-append date datetimepicker" data-date="12-12-2012"
data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
   <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" value="12-12-2012">
   <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>

<div id="view"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
     format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii',
     todayBtn: true,
     pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
   });
});

$(document.body).on('change', ".datetimepicker", function(e){
   var date = $(".datetimepicker").getDate();
   $("#view").html(date);
});
```

I get the error

> Object [object Object] has no method 'getDate'

So clearly I have some error but can't find it and in documentation I can't find how to extract the date from the field. Please help!

Comment: first of all that's not a error try `console.log(date);` see what and all in those object and try to print those.

Comment: ok I printed them but they are too much to post them here more than 1000 chars...

Comment: Where do you put your scripts and do you put them in the correct order?

Comment: Yea the datetimepicker is showing everything is working just I wonder how to extract the date value

Comment: it says '_changeDate_' and _e.date.valueOf()_ in that bootstrap page

Comment: have you tried **ev.date.valueOf()** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datetimepicker')
  .datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:ii',
    todayBtn: true,
    pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
  })
  .on('changeDate', function(ev){
     $("#view").html(ev.date.valueOf());
  });
```

});

OK, I've done this is the code I needed thanks to @acudars and @rps

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    console.log(ev.date.valueOf());
});
```

or

```
$(document.body).on('change', ".datetimepicker", function(e){
   var date = e.date.valueOf();
   $("#view").html(date);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document.body).on('changeDate', ".datetimepicker", function(e){
   var date = e.date.valueOf();
   $("#view").html(date);
});
```